# How to fix *** URI::InvalidComponentError Exception: bad password component?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/http/digest_auth'

digest_auth = Net::HTTP::DigestAuth.new

uri = URI.parse 'http://localhost:8000/'
uri.user = 'username'
uri.password = "%PsC\;=sQ}X4DWA%K"
```

And I get:

```
*** URI::InvalidComponentError Exception: bad password component
```

I tried escaping some characters with no luck. What is causing this exception?

Comment: It seems your password is not compliant with URI validating regex, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thanks Marek! Is there a way to monkeypatch this validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the userinfo part of URIs (according to RFC 3986), you can use [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) to describe characters outside of the basic allowed alphabet of `/[a-ZA-Z0-9._~-]/`. This works by writing the `%` character followed by two hex characters, describing an octet.

Since your password contains unescaped percent characters which are followed by non-hex characters, it doesn't follow this encoding scheme and is thus rejected by Ruby.

To use your current password in a URL, you have to manually escape the password (specifically the percent characters in your case) before assigning it:

```
password = '%PsC\;=sQ}X4DWA%K'
escaped_password = URI.escape(password)
# => "%25PsC%5C;=sQ%7DX4DWA%25K"

uri.password = escaped_password
```

Note that similar restrictions apply to other parts of URIs such as the path and hostname. Depending on the part, different escaping rules apply. Please refer to the respective RFCs for details.

Also, when literally pasting passwords in your code (which is often insecure and is generally avoided everywhere but in simple one-off scripts in order to better protect those secrets), make sure to escape any special characters interpreted by the Ruby parser itself (such as backslash characters). You can avoid most of these Ruby parser issues by using single-quoted strings here.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that they need to watch out for that backslash, `"%PsC\;=sQ}X4DWA%K"` and `'%PsC\;=sQ}X4DWA%K'` are different strings.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks Holger!